# Columns in excel

Tags: excel

Say in column A I have 1,000 values. I want to count the number of times the word "blue" is used in that column.

The only two constraints are:

1. It does not just have to be just the word in each cell, it can be a phrase as well. For example, "blue sky" or "blue jeans".
2. If there are repeats of the word that should only count as one occurrence. (i.e "blue blue blue" in the same cell should only count as one occurrence of blue).

What are some ways I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use COUNTIF with wild cards`*`

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"*"& "blue" & "*")
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much! Do you know of any other methods or functions  outside of `COUNTIF` I can use to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: None that are as efficient as COUNTIF.  Why?  Any other would require the use of an array type formula and will be much slower. @ogk  It Can Be done with SUMPRODUCT, but again you will need to limit the reference to the data set instead of the full column reference and it will be slower.

Comment: Understood, my goal is to compare the most efficient way and a less efficient way just to see how big of a difference using the correct function would be. Could you explain how to use `SUMPRODUCT` to accomplish this?

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("blue",A1:A11))))` @ogk

Comment: Thanks again, so new issue I've run into: Say `blue` has a value associated to it of `01` and `02`. And `blue` appears 20 times within my column. How do I find out how many unique values it has associated with it? In the example I described above the function should return a value of 2

Comment: New question = new post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41252238/how-to-find-how-many-unique-values-are-associated-with-a-word-in-excel here we go