# How to find how many unique values are associated with a word in excel

Tags: excel, count, unique

Say I have one column called colors with 1000 cells populated with values. Some of the cells have the word `blue` in it. In another column I have unique identifiers that correspond with the colors column. For example `Blue` can have a value associated to it of 01, 02, 04, or 05. The word `blue` appears 20 times within my name column. What is one way I can find how many unique identifiers are associated with the word `blue`?

In the example listed above the answer should return 4.

The current method I am using to accomplish this is by using a pivot table. I filter out any value in the name column that doesnt include the word `blue`. Then I count all the unique identifiers that appear in my pivot table.

[image]

EDIT: Notice how `blue` appears 8 times, but it only has the values 1, 2, 3, and 4 associated with it. How can I create a function that finds out how many values are associated with blue?

Comment: Are the unique identifiers stored as text or values? If values you can use something like: https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-values-in-a-range-with-countif or if text: https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-text-values-in-a-range. You can then replace the ranges they use with array conditionals that will only pull rows that have `Blue`. Hope this gets you started.

Comment: Can you share an example of how your sheet is set up. It's difficult to understand "In another column I have unique identifiers that correspond with the colors column." What do both columns look like with some sample data.

Comment: @JNevill edited in a pic and a better explaination

Answer (score 0):

One option:

In Excel versions that support Power Pivot, add the data to the data model, build a pivot table and use the "Distinct Count" as the aggregation of the values.

[image]

Without Power Pivot, build a regular pivot table with the value field (bad wording of the field, sorry) nested under the colors field, then use Countif on the color column of the pivot table.

[image]

Comment: Thats the method I've been using, but I was wondering if there's a way to do this with only functions and no pivot table

Comment: Is it possible to not use a pivot table at all?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is located at `A1:B21` try this:

Enter the following headers at `D1:F1`

[image]

Enter these `ArrayFormulas`

*`FormulaArrays` are entered pressing* <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> *simultaneously, you shall see* `{` *and* `}` *around the formula if entered correctly*

In `D2` - Returns an unique combined list of `Colors` & `Values`:

```
=IFERROR(
INDEX($A$2:$A$21&$B$2:$B$21,
MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$1:$D1,$A$2:$A$21&$B$2:$B$21),0)*1),"")
```

[image]

In `E2` - Returns an unique list of `Colors`:

```
=IFERROR(
INDEX($A$2:$A$21,
MATCH(0,COUNTIF($E$1:$E1,$A$2:$A$21),0)*1),"")
```

[image]

In `F2` - Returns the count of combined `Colors` & `Values` for each `Color`:

```
=COUNTIF($D$2:$D$21,$E2&"*")
```

[image]

Then copy the `ArrayFormulas` in `D2:F2` till last row of data (i.e. row 21)

*Column `D` could be hidden if required...*

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the answer in the first comment, you can filter it with something like this (not tested):

```
= SUMPRODUCT( IFERROR(1 / COUNTIFS(A2:A21, "Blue", B2:B21, B2:B21), 0) )
```